# react-recaptha - grecaptcha is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, recaptcha

I have successfully implemented [react-recaptcha](https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha) in my react / redux project and it works in most situations. For example, when a user navigates to my signup page from another route, it loads perfectly. However, when a user refreshes the signup page with recaptcha on it, 3/4 times I get:
`grecaptcha is not defined`

I think this is race condition because when I work locally, I do not get this error. Here's how I have my code setup:

**index.html**

```
<head>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
</head>
```

**Signup.jsx**

```
...
<Recaptcha {...captcha} sitekey='xxx-xxx-xxx'  
     render = 'explicit'  
     verifyCallback={this.verifyCallback}  
     data-size="compact"  
     onloadCallback={this.captchaLoadCallback}  
     style={this.captchaStyle}  
     size='small' />  
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since your recaptcha script file is loaded in `async defer` way your problem can happens when `<Recaptcha />` fires before `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js` is downloaded. It happens on signup page. If you navigate from other page than signup your script will be ready and `<Recaptcha />` will work fine.

You have 2 options:

1. Remove `async defer` - not recommended.
2. Handle callback when `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js` is ready and register only then your `<Recaptcha />`.